# Highcharts point click event returns "hover" state instead of "select" state

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using Highcharts 4.1.1. I'm showing a div with more information if a point is selected. I want to hide the div if all points are unselected. I figured I could use the `click` event. If I log the `event` to the console, I can inspect it and see that the value of `point.state` is "select" and `point.selected` is true. But if I try logging `event.point.state` (rather than just the `event`) the result is "hover". Because of this I can't use the `event.point.selected` value since it's sometimes undefined.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                marker: {
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            $("#pointState").html("State: " + event.point.state + "<br>" + "Selected? " + event.point.selected);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1gsqq8yr/1/

Click on any point, and note the State is "hover". Why? Click on the same point again and the state is "select" but the `selected` value is "true" (shouldn't it be false?). I've tried setting the hover state `enabled` value to false, but that just then returns undefined. Don't really know what's going on here.

Comment: Getting `state: "select"` on Chrome....

Comment: @RobertRozas, when are you seeing the `select` state? I tried in Chrome as well, and clicking on a point, that's not already selected, shows me "hover" in the `p` below the graph (in the fiddle). Again, if I check the console though, the state is select.

Comment: When i inspect the Ga object the state is select....it's kind of weird(bug maybe)...you can use `event.type` instead...

Comment: Yes, for some reason (unless I'm misunderstanding something or doing something wrong), inspecting the state will always show `select`. But if you try to use the state value, in an if statement for example, the state value will sometimes be hover. `event.type` doesn't really work as a substitute since it's always `click`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing going on is that **before** the chart changes the selected state of that point, it will run your code therefore it brings you the **previous selected state** of the point.

That's why the selected property is the opposite every time, that is why **returning false cancels the operation** because it has not yet been triggered. I don't know any workarounds in the API, but you could check the states and return the opposites to your liking:

```
var state = (this.state == "hover")? "selected" : "hover";
var selected = (this.selected == true) ? "false" : "true";
$("#pointState").html("State: " + state + "<br>" + "Selected? " + selected);
```

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1gsqq8yr/2/).

Comment: @Braffin Is it so hard to comment on something?